# how to upload base64 encoded png of signature to server in react native

Tags: javascript, image, react-native, base64, fetch

I am new to react native. I am trying to upload the base64 encoded png to server using formData. but I am keep getting error. network request failed. please help. thanks.
here is the code

```
this.setState({base64: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${result.encoded}`})
console.log(this.state.base64)

  formData.append('digital_signature', 
           {
             
               uri:this.state.base64,         
              // uri: this.state.singleFileADH1,
              name: 'digital_signature.jpg',
              type: 'image/*'
          }
       );

   fetch('https://abc.tech/Android_API_CI/upload_multipart_data',
      {
        method: 'post',
          body : formData,
          
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;',
        },
        
      }

<SignatureCapture
          style={styles.signature}
          ref="sign"
          onSaveEvent={this._onSaveEvent}
          onDragEvent={this._onDragEvent}
          showNativeButtons={false}
          // minStrokeWidth={-10}
          // saveImage={true}
          showTitleLabel={false}
          viewMode={'portrait'}
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 const file = {
      uri:
        Platform.OS == 'android'
          ? ImageUri.path
          : `file://${ImageUri.path}`,
      name: 'image.jpg',
      type: ImageUri.mime, // e.g. 'image/jpg'
    };
    formdata.append('user_photo', file);
```

may this help you

Comment: but there is no file in that path

Comment: ImageUri.path it means use your file path where you put that file ex . you store your your photo etc in you phone then only use that path and api auto take that photo from their.

Comment: yes I use result.pathName see this = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66793379/how-to-save-store-signature-image-in-app-or-phone-internal-storage-in-react-nat

Comment: give you ans their check .