# How to save/store signature image in app or phone internal storage. in react native

Tags: javascript, image, react-native, path, digital-signature

I am new to react native. I am trying to store signature in my mobile internal storage. or in app itself. but I do not know how to store this signature image in phone internal storage or in app storage. please help . here is code

```
base64:null,

_onSaveEvent = (result) => {

  this.setState({base64: result.pathName})
  console.log(this.state.base64)


                            <SignatureCapture
                              style={styles.signature}
                              ref="sign"
                              onSaveEvent={this._onSaveEvent}
                              onDragEvent={this._onDragEvent}
                              showNativeButtons={false}
                              showTitleLabel={false}
                              viewMode={'portrait'}
                            />
}
```

result.pathName return this path =

```
/storage/emulated/0/saved_signature/signature.png
```

but there is know folder caller saved_signature. so what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    npm install --save rn-fetch-blob

For android only AndroidManifest.xml
<!-- Required -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<!-- Include this only if you are planning to use the camera roll -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Include this only if you are planning to use the microphone for video recording -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>


<!-- Required -->
<application  android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... />

// check for permission
const checkAndroidPermission = async () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      save();
    } else {
      try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        );
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          // Once user grant the permission start downloading

          save();
        } else {
          if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            ToastAndroid.show('Storage Permission denied.', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
          } else {
            AlertIOS.alert('Storage Permission denied.');
          }
        }
      } catch (err) {
        // To handle permission related exception
        console.warn('tryerr', err);
      }
    }
  };
  
   const save= async () => {
      const paths = `${
        RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DCIMDir
      }/${new Date().getTime()}.jpg`; // where u need to put that 
      try {
        RNFetchBlob.fs
          .writeFile(paths, data.base64, 'base64')//data.base64 is your photo with convert base64
          .then((value) => {
              RNFetchBlob.fs
                .scanFile([{path: paths}]) //after save to notify gallry for that
                .then(() => {
                  console.log('scan file success');
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                  console.log('scan file error');
                });
          })
          .catch((e) => console.log(e.message));
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('fileerror', error.message);
      }
    
}
```

my this help you

Comment: at last else their is = ';' expected.ts(1005)

Comment: pleas edit my code if you are free I  am not getting where should I put my result

Comment: give me your result log so  I can edit my ans

Comment: my rsult.pathName = /storage/emulated/0/saved_signature/signature.png, result.encoded = {base64 png data}, result = [object , bject]

Comment: your hole result log not result.pathname

Comment: when I console only result I am getting object object

Comment: use JSON.stringfy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230351/discussion-between-ankit-patel-and-sohil-shaikh).

Comment: hey. my image now showing  in internal stoarge thanks but Image not sending to server not uploading to server . please help

Comment: right now I m little bit busy so please ask some one

Answer (score 0):

use this to store your photo in internal storage [rn-fatch-blob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-fetch-blob)
if you don't understand this then told me i will share a code also to store a file in your photo with custom folder path

Comment: yes please tell me how to do that i really dont know how to use this rn-fetch-blob